# ASP.NET MVC 3: Session and Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, session

i have asp.net mvc 3 site with Forms Authentication and Session with SQLServer mode. Today I try to set authentication mode="None" and store auth-token in cookie (because authorization token i get from remote service) and check is cookie exist at `Application_BeginRequest` in `global.asax`, if no - user redirected to logon page.
After authetication I store user in session: `HttpContext.Current.Session[userToken]`.
When I set authentication mode="None" at first look it works as expected - user redirected to logon, submit form with login and password and after that, on next request HttpContext.Current.Session is null. 
I don't know why it becomes null?

Comment: You are asking us to imagine what your code looks like. Unfortunately it doesn't work that way. Post some code and we can help.. Maybe :)

Comment: I can think of a few reasons maybe, need some code man

Comment: Maybe your cookie expires? Did you set the expiration time? If you did not, then it will be destroyed after each session.

Comment: Still no code? We need to see how you are setting your FormsAuthTicket

Answer (score 0):

When you are accessing the Session[userToken] in the BeingRequest event of your Request pipeline, The Session has not been loaded yet.